# pxfont upgreek... Why can't i use?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, greek, libertine, newtxmath

I'm trying to use **pxfont**  upright greek letters in math as the way below but it doesn't work. When i write `\alpha` I would like to see `\upalpha` from px. My main  font is libertine.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine,liby,libaltvw,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{npxmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{27}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{28}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{29}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{39}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\partial}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{64}

\renewcommand{\alpha}{\upalpha}
\renewcommand{\beta}{\upbeta}
\renewcommand{\theta}{\uptheta}
\renewcommand{\gamma}{\upgamma}
\renewcommand{\sigma}{\upsigma}
\renewcommand{\varepsilon}{\upvarepsilon}
\renewcommand{\delta}{\updelta}
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\upepsilon}
\renewcommand{\zeta}{\upzeta}
\renewcommand{\eta}{\upeta}
\renewcommand{\kappa}{\upkappa}
\renewcommand{\lambda}{\uplambda}
\renewcommand{\mu}{\upmu}
\renewcommand{\nu}{\upnu}
\renewcommand{\xi}{\upxi}
\renewcommand{\pi}{\uppi}
\renewcommand{\rho}{\uprho}
\renewcommand{\upsilon}{\upupsilon}
\renewcommand{\phi}{\upphi}
\renewcommand{\chi}{\upchi}
\renewcommand{\psi}{\uppsi}
\renewcommand{\omega}{\upomega}
\renewcommand{\varepsilon}{\upvarepsilon}
\renewcommand{\vartheta}{\upvartheta}
\renewcommand{\varpi}{\upvarpi}
\renewcommand{\varphi}{\upvarphi}
\renewcommand{\varpi}{\upvarpi}
\renewcommand{\varsigma}{\upvarsigma}
\renewcommand{\varrho}{\upvarrho}
\begin{document}
$\alpha\beta\gamma\mu\varpi\pi\varsigma\sigma\rho\zeta\delta\varepsilon$

These letters should come from pxfont.
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the title and the first sentence of your posting, you say you want to use the `pxfonts` upright Greek characters. However, in the MWE you load the `newtxmath` package. Are you maybe more interested in the `newpxmath` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine,liby,libaltvw,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{U}{pxmia}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{27}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{28}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{29}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{39}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\partial}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{64}    
\begin{document}
$\alpha\beta\gamma\mu\varpi\pi\varsigma\sigma\rho\zeta\delta\varepsilon$

These letters should come from pxfont.
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
name                   type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
---------------------- ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
XIJCAC+Pxmia           Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       4  0
RMSEWS+LinLibertineT   Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
```